# Double click on Safari title bar to fit screen

Tags: safari, fullscreen

When I double-click on the title bar of most Apps they automatically fit the whole screen.
If I do so in Safari it only fits the height.

[image]

If I want it to fit the width as well I have to double click on both upper corners as well. I do not want to switch to full screen mode. What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

[image]
Is there some way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Not really an answer, but this has been standard behaviour since *forever* with no simple workround.

Comment: Are you using a computer with Intel (x86) or Apple M1 (ARM)?